# Firefox addon - port.emit inside port.on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried to code the following but it seems unresponsive or i am missing something:

main.js - main addon code

```
panel.port.on("request", function(){
     panel.port.emit("yes");
}
```

panel.js - content script

```
self.port.emit("request");
self.port.on("yes", function(){ window.alert("yes"); });
```

Is it legal to have a communication of this type? and if yes why is it non functional?

Thanks

Aiden

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed. There are even examples in [the official documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html) using this scheme.

> and if yes why is it non functional?

Your order is wrong. You're calling `self.port.on("yes", ...)` only after `panel.port.emit("yes", ...)` was already called. Switch the two content script lines, and stuff should work.